# Can someone help to solve a non-linear ODE using the Runge-Kutta method?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, nonlinear-analysis, runge-kutta-methods, nonlinear-dynamics

I am doing a literature survey on charged particle dynamics. In a paper the plots between the parameters $(r, \theta, \phi)$ as $r$ vs $\theta$, $\phi$ ($\theta$ vs $\phi$) of the equation :
$$
\frac{d^2 \theta(t)}{dt^2} = 
\frac{1}{r(t)} \left(-2 \frac{dr(t)}{dt} \frac{d\theta(t)}{dt} -
r(t) \left(\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt} + \Omega\right)^2 \sin \theta(t) \cos \theta(t) \right) + \\
+ q \left(r(t) \frac{d\phi(t)}{dt} \sin \theta(t)\right) B_r - \frac{dr(t)}{dt} B_\phi. \\
\Omega = 4.5.
$$ using Runge-Kutta method is given.
I have tried to reproduce the same but cant. Any suggestion or guide would be great. Bring down second order to first order is of no help as the three variable (parameters) are still in the equation.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the paper?

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1029/JA088iA07p05607     Consolmagno,G. J., Lorentz force on the dust in Jupiter's Rings,J. Geophys.Res.,88, 5607-5612, 198

Comment: You can't solve a single equation for three unknowns. You need separate equations for $r(t)$ and $\phi(t)$. And initial conditions too.

Comment: @uranix. You are right. there are other two equations for theta and phi. without solving can't we can l plot between r, theta and phi? R, theta and phi are the standard spherical polar co ordinates. By the way, how do you typed phi, theta here?

Comment: About MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: So you have 3 second order equations for $r, \phi, \theta$. You need to rewrite them as 6 first order equiation itroducing $\dot r = v, \dot \phi = \omega, \dot \theta = \gamma$. Then plug the right hand side of the ODE to any RK solver

Comment: @uranix Thank you. I shall try and if get stuck or unable to get the plots please bear with me I might have to bother you again.

Comment: @uranix, for evaluations of K1 and l1, k2, and l2 etc. what would be the  values θ, r ϕ, will it be θ(0), r(0), ϕ(0)? As per the RK4, we have k1 = hf{ v(0)+h/2, ω(0) +h/2, γ(0) + h/2}

Comment: Runge-Kutta build solution in steps. On each step you have $r(t_n), \phi(t_n), \theta(t_n), v(t_n), \omega(t_n), \gamma(t_n)$. Then RK step gives you an approximation for $r(t_{n+1}), \phi(t_{n+1}), \theta(t_{n+1}), v(t_{n+1}), \omega(t_{n+1}), \gamma(t_{n+1})$ at $t_{n+1} = t_n + h$. The answer to you question: they should be $r(t_n), \dots, \gamma(t_n)$, not $r(0), \dots, \gamma(0)$.

Comment: @uranix. Thank you so much.I wish that there are more people like you in every educational institution to share their knowledge to the younger generations. My prayers and gratitude for you.